# How send email with NTLM authentication from laravel?

Tags: php, email, laravel, ntlm

i have code like this in laravel to send email

```
 public static function send_email(){
      Mail::send('emails.g', array(), function($message){
         $message->from('leo_messi@barcelona.com', 'lol');
         $message->to('neymar@barcelona.com')->subject('LOL LOL');
      });
     }
```

my email config file is like this

```
return array(
    'driver' => 'smtp',
    'host' => '{host ip here}',
    'port' => 25,
    'from' => array('address' => null, 'name' => null),
  //  'encryption' => 'ssl', 
    'username' => "leo_messi@barcelona.com",
    'password' => "lollol",
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'pretend' => false,

);
```

i can send mail from my gmail account using above code. but i want to send email from local exchange server (NTLM authentication). above code is not working for exchange server.
whats wrong with me?

Answer (score -1):

You need to use imap or pop3, I have only ever managed to do it with pop3 and imap. But you can configure MS exchange to allow these protocols with a username and password.